# An implementation for the double factorial

Tags: python, recursion, iteration

I have written this piece of code that implements the double factorial in Python both iteratively and recursively; the code works without problems, but I'm interested in improving my overall programming style. Here's the code:

```
def semif_r(n):                 #recursive implementation
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        z = 1
    else:
        z= n * semif_r(n-2)
    return z


def semif_i(n):             #iterative implementation
    N = 1
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1
    elif n%2 == 1:
        for i in range(0,n/2):
            N =  (2*i + 1)*N
            VAL = N
        return n*VAL

    elif n%2 == 0:
        for i in range(0,n/2):
            N =  (2*i+2)*N
            VAL = N
    return VAL
```

I hope that some experienced programmers can give me some feedback about improving my code!

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question could be suitable for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), as long as (a) your code works as intended, (b) your code is real code, rather than example code, and (c) your code is included in the body of the question. If you wish for a peer review to improve all aspects of your code, please post it on Code Review.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [codereview.se].

Comment: This question has now been [cross-posted on Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/111433/an-implementation-for-the-double-factorial).

Comment: What happens for large `n`, e.g. `n == 2000`?

Comment: If you want it to be robust you might want to query [**`sys.getrecursionlimit`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getrecursionlimit).

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand why you need the `VAL` variable since it is equal to `N`; just use `N`.

You may write: `N *= (2*i + 1)` rather than `N = (2*i + 1)*N` but if you don't want to use this way, maybe it would still be better to write `N = N * (2*i + 1)` because it is easier to read.

For arithmetic functions, write `n//2` rather than `n/2` because both are different in Python 3; writing `n//2` is more portable accross the different versions of Python.

As a challenge, you may want to try writing a third version as a tail-recursive function by using the `tco` module: http://baruchel.github.io/python/2015/11/07/explaining-functional-aspects-in-python/

Comment: Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 1):

```
from operator import mul
semif_pythonic = lambda x: reduce(mul, xrange(x, 1, -2))
```